# How to build AmazonSQS with proxy settings

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I need to create an AmazonSQS that goes through a specific proxy (not using jvm defaults). I want to use all of the standard defaults and only change the proxy. Is there any easy way to set the proxy information? So far this is what I have.

```
AmazonSQSClientBuilder builder = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard();
AmazonSQS sqsClient = builder.withClientConfiguration(
    builder.getClientConfiguration()
    .withProxyHost("hostname")
    .withProxyPort(port)
    .withNonProxyHosts("no proxy hosts"))
    .build()
```

This results in a NPE on `builder.getClientConfiguration().withProxyHost("hostname")`. How do I set client configuration in the builder to a configuration with defaults and then setup the proxy info?

Comment: I haven't done this (so this is not an answer), but I think you want to replace `builder.getClientConfiguration()` with `PredefinedClientConfigurations.defaultConfig()`.

Comment: If that did work for you, you should add it as an answer. If it didn't you should say so so that other people can give you alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`builder` did not have a configuration set. Using PredefinedClientConfigurations fixed this.

```
AmazonSQSClientBuilder builder = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard();
AmazonSQS sqsClient = builder.withClientConfiguration(
    PredefinedClientConfigurations.defaultConfig()
    .withProxyHost("hostname")
    .withProxyPort(port)
    .withNonProxyHosts("no proxy hosts"))
    .build()
```

This will create an AmazonSQS with all of the defaults and a proxy host setup.

Comment: Ideally, you should set the proxy at the system (env) level and then leverage that (defaultConfig()) to read it w/o need to explicitly provide that in code.